# How to use a string as code to initialize another string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, variables, char, initialization

I have a long list of strings such as:

```
"njro\x68qgbx"\xe4af\"\\suan"
```

As you all know, those could be understood as a string initializing code-command such as:

```
string com = "njro\x68qgbx\"\\xe4af\\\"\\\\suan";
Console.WriteLine(com);
```

Output: njrohqgbx"\xe4af"\suan
Char-Count: 22

Converting \x68 to h, "" indicating where the value starts & ends, and " showing that " should be part of the output value and not be seen as an indicator.

But it could also be seen as one whole string value, with

```
string val = @"""njro\x68qgbx\"\\xe4af\\\"\\\\suan""";
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Output: "njro\x68qgbx"\xe4af"\suan"
Char-Count: 29

Outputting the whole value.

For a Day 8 in the Advent of Code Challenge 2015, I have over 1000 of these kinds of strings. I have to write a code that counts the number of characters of the output-string (if the string is used initialize an other string as code) and subtract it from the actual number of code characters.

Of course, I could write a bunch of logic for every possible case (for example, if char \ followed by \ value of total = 1). But I believe there has to be an easier way.

So : **Is there a way to use a string as the initializing code-text for another string?** In that way, I could initialize it once as a whole string and once use it as initializing text and then just count characters. I am very thankful for your help!

I tried Reading in the Lines, splitting them by char an writing a logic for all cases but that gets very long and subsceptible for mistakes. So i want to find a smarter way!

```
using System.Reflection;

var x = File.ReadAllLines(@"text.txt");

var list = new List<char[]>();
foreach (var y in x)
{
    var chararr = y.ToCharArray();
    list.Add(chararr);
}
int counter = 0;
foreach (char[] arr in list)
{
     int i = 1; 
     foreach (char k in arr)
     {
     if (k == '\\' && arr[i-1]=='\\')
         counter += 1;
     //Write a bunch of Logic to get the count of chars that the compiler would be outputting.
     i++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Never used this, but how about [Regex.Unescape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_)?

Comment: t´Thx im going to try that.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex `Unescape(String input)` method it returns a string of characters with any escaped characters converted to their unescaped form.

> Read official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_).